# event organiser not loading in main content area

Tags: widgets

there is possibly a very simple answer for this, but im afraid im a novice at this stuff :(

on my wordpress site Im using the event list shortcode in the main content area and the calendar in the sidebar.  however whenver I click on an event to view it in full, either from the list or from the actual calendar...it loads it up in the sidebar and not the main content area.

I hope you can help :)
thank you very much! I really like the plugin, I just cant seem to get it the work as i would like.

thanks
ross

Comment: Have you tried using the shortcode only in one area? You might be confusing the plugin as to where it needs to display its information.

Comment: still the same problem.  it always loads it in the sidebar.  Is there a way of telling it where to open?

Answer (score 1):

The page you go to is the single event page.

The problem is that the plug-in provided default templates (see the `templates` directory - for category, venue, single event and event archive pages) do not work with every theme.

The solution is simple, copy these template files into your theme folder and edit them there so that they work with your theme. You can also decide what information is displayed and where using various functions provided by the plug-in. The easiest way to do this is to start with an existing template from your theme as a basis - and work from that adding in template functions to display dates, venues, categories etc.

For more information see the [documentation on editing the templates](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/event-organiser/documentation/editing-the-templates/). Also see the [function reference](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/event-organiser/documentation/function-reference/) for functions available to you in the templates.